# foreach loop with in foreach to insert unique record in database for each item in array

Tags: php

I have two arrays one is associative and second one is non associative i want to insert for each item of each array as a row  in the database. In my code below $menu and $id are array . This $id part is giving me error as this itself is an array  .... error says "array to string conversion".  Please help!!!

```
foreach($menu as $label => $link) {
    $id = $request->themeLocation;
    DB::table('menus')->insertGetId([ 'label' => $label ,'url' => $link ,'child_id' =>'child-'.$id ,'menu_status' => 1  ]); 
}
```

after applying foreach with in foreach i am  geting hierarchy entries in DB

```
       id   child id    url     label   menu_status

       41   child-38    about   ABOUT US    1
       42   child-39    about   ABOUT US    1
       43   child-40    about   ABOUT US    1
       44   child-38    services    Services    1
       45   child-39    services    Services    1
       46   child-40    services    Services    1
       47   child-38    contact contact 1
       48   child-39    contact contact 1
       49   child-40    contact contact 1
```

but i am getting redundant entries in DB i want this result

```
       41   child-38    about   ABOUT US    1
       42   child-39    services    Services    1
       43   child-40    contact contact 1
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: So, `$id = $request->themeLocation;` creates a numeric index array into `$id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are trying to do, this would be a way:

```
$i = 0;
$id = $request->themeLocation;

foreach($menu as $label => $link) {
    DB::table('menus')->insertGetId([ 'label' => $label ,'url' => $link ,'child_id' =>'child-'.$id[$i] ,'menu_status' => 1  ]);
    $i++;
}
```

I understand `$id` content is ["38", "39", "40"], so you have to access to its content with a numeric index ($i).

Comment: thanks nanocv !! you get me right ..... your given solution is working like a charm .. Thanks alot

Comment: just for my experience i want to know , what if $request->themeLocation was not having numeric index ,means if it was associative index then ???

Comment: @wasimbeg That's it! You have those two types of arrays in PHP: indexed array (with numeric keys) and associative array (with named keys). Here is very well explained: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp